# Questions about some subgroups...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to ask if I'm understand few subgroups correct:

1. $\langle 2\rangle$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\left\{2\cdot n\big|n\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$
2. $\langle 2\rangle$ of $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is $\left\{2^{n}\big|n\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$
3. $\langle i\rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\left\{i\cdot n\big|n\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$
4. $\langle i\rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is $\left\{i^{0},i^{1},i^{2},i^{3} \right\}=\left\{1,i,-1,-i \right\}$

I'm right?

If not, please tell me...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ to be the additive group of reals and the additive group of complex numbers, and by $\mathbb R^*$ and $\mathbb C^*$ the non-zero reals and complex numbers under multiplication, then yes, you're correct in your understanding of the subgroups generated by $2$ in the first two cases, and those generated by $i$ in the second two cases. The only finite group here, of course, is the last. And indeed, they are all cyclic groups, by definition, and any subgroup generated by one element of a group is the smallest subgroup containing that element.

Comment: Well, they're all cyclic, of course...

Comment: @BenMillwood how the first three are cyclic?

Comment: Any group generated by an element alone is cyclic: it's the smallest sub-group containing the generating element.

Comment: @amWhy: did you edit your post to remove mention of cyclic-ness, or am I going mad? (or, indeed, both...)

Comment: @YoavFridman: the groups of which your generated groups are subgroups are not cyclic: $(\mathbb R, +), (\mathbb R^*, \cdot), (\mathbb C, +), (\mathbb C^*, \cdot)$ are not cyclic. But the subgroups generated by $2$, $i$, respectively ARE cyclic.

Comment: @BenMillwood I did edit to *add* mention of "cyclic-ness".

Answer (score 1):

General hint:

If $G$ is a group and $\emptyset\neq M\subseteq G$, then $$\langle M\rangle=\{x_1^{\epsilon_1}x_2^{\epsilon_2}\cdots x_n^{\epsilon_n}\mid x_i\in M,~\epsilon_i\in\mathbb Z, n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}$$ for example in $(\mathbb Z,+)$, $\langle 2\rangle=\{2k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$. or in $(\mathbb Q,+)$ $$\langle \{3,\frac{1}2\}\rangle=\{3k+\frac{l}{2}\mid~k,l\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: thanks. the same for you. :-)